# Pass content of system messages to HTML Email Template

Tags: emails

I know I can set the template in the email settings to use a HTML template but how do I pass the content of the system messages (activate your account, reset your password, etc) to this template?

I've added this to the html template but then the email that is sent is blank:

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[EmailService->sendEmailByKey()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/apis/emailservice#sendEmailByKey) sets the `htmlBody` property of `EmailModel` to this:

```
$emailModel->htmlBody = "{% extends '{$template}' %}\n".
    "{% set body %}\n".
        $emailModel->htmlBody.
    "{% endset %}\n";
```

So if you've got a custom email template in `craft/templates/email.html`, in the control panel under Settings → Email → HTML Email Template, you'd set the value to `email.html`.

And you'd simply output the dynamic email content in your template by using `{{ body }}` like so:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            {{ body }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```